# Testing Django allauth

Tags: python, django, facebook, testing, django-allauth

I am trying to test my app but not sure how to configure the django-allauth in the test environment. I am getting:

`ImproperlyConfigured: No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin`

My approach so far is to instantiate app objects inside `tests.py` with actual Facebook app parameters, an app which functions correctly locally in the browser:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp

apper = SocialApp.objects.create(provider=u'facebook', 
    name=u'fb1', client_id=u'7874132722290502',
    secret=u'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
apper.sites.create(domain='localhost:8000', name='creyu.org')
```

How can I get these tests running? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where inside `tests.py` do you instantiate this app object? If it's inside the `setUpModule()` method, there shouldn't be a problem.

Personally, I would create a fixture `init_facebook_app.json` with the relevant information and then inside `tests.py` (before the test cases) define:

```
from django.core.management import call_command    

def setUpModule():
    call_command('loaddata', 'init_facebook_app.json', verbosity=0)
```

This ensures that the data in the fixture are loaded before the tests are run, and that they are loaded only once, i.e. not before each test. See this for [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) regarding call_command.

Lastly, posting your Facebook app secret key anywhere on the internet is not a good idea - I would reset it if I were you.

Comment: I had instantiated the app object inside of a Testcase `def`.

Fixtures would be great, except I'm getting endless woes along the lines of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857406/django-unable-to-load-test-fixtures-integrityerror which is what I get when using your setUpModule solution. Any other ideas?

Re: Secret key: I appreciate the concern but I had randomised it before posting.

Comment: Hmm, I'm at loss. Try creating the fixture manually, just to see whether that works. Something along the lines of `[{"pk": 1, "model": "sites.site", "fields": {"domain": "127.0.0.1:8000", "name": "creyu.org"}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "socialaccount.socialapp", "fields": {"name": "Facebook", "sites": [1], "secret": "XXX", "client_id": "XXX", "key": "", "provider": "facebook"}}]`

Comment: Again, that chokes with `ImproperlyConfigured`. I took the specific fixture segments direct from the data dumps to ensure validity. It must require more somehow. Perhaps I need to face up to the main fixture errors noted above. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to overcome the fixture problem so your answer is the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11409794/770513 Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a migration so all your environments have the data

eg

```
import os
from django.db import models, migrations
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.conf import settings

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def add_initial_providers(apps, schema_editor):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        call_command(
            'loaddata',
            os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,         'fixtures/social_auth.json'),
        verbosity=0)

dependencies = [
    ('my_app', '001_auto_20160128_1846'),
]


operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(add_initial_providers),
]
```